# C# tab control left horizontal alignment with picture

Tags: c#, image, winforms, addition, tabcontrol

I have followed the instructions in the msdn website:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms404305%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
to display a tab control as the following picture:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
private void tcMain_DrawItem(Object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Brush _textBrush;

    TabPage _tabPage = tcMain.TabPages[e.Index];
    Rectangle _tabBounds = tcMain.GetTabRect(e.Index);

    if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
    {
        _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
        e.DrawBackground();
    }

    Font _tabFont = new Font("Times New Roman", (float)22, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();
    _stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
    _stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    g.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, _tabFont, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));
}
```

Now I want to add a picture to the left of the tab control buttons? I mean, how to show a picture to the left of the word Book for example?

After trying some answers from below I ended up with the code:

```
private void tcMain_DrawItem(Object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Brush _textBrush;

        TabPage _tabPage = tcMain.TabPages[e.Index];
        Rectangle _tabBounds = tcMain.GetTabRect(e.Index);

        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
            e.DrawBackground();
        }

        tcMain.ImageList = imgList;
        tcMain.TabPages[0].ImageIndex = 1;
        tcMain.TabPages[1].ImageIndex = 0;
        tcMain.TabPages[2].ImageIndex = 3;
        tcMain.TabPages[3].ImageIndex = 2;

        Rectangle tabImage = tcMain.GetTabRect(e.Index);
        tabImage.Size = new Size(40, 40);

        g.DrawImage(tcMain.ImageList.Images[_tabPage.ImageIndex], tabImage);

        Font _tabFont = new Font("Times New Roman", (float)22, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();
        _stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        _stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        g.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, _tabFont, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));
    }
```

Then when I take a snapshot to the results it comes like this:
[image]

[image]

Refreshing all the time

Comment: You are already handling the drawing yourself.  Use the `Graphics` object to draw whatever picture you like, wherever you like.

Comment: Would you please do some coding? and where exactly I should put it?

Comment: Why don't you try to write some code yourself? You put a DrawImage it along with the DrawString, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `ImageList` control to your project and add some images to it and set the `ImageIndex` property of your `TabPages`. Then just use `DrawImage()` method in your `DrawItem` event.

```
Rectangle tabImage = tcMain.GetTabRect(e.Index);
tabImage.Size = new Size(16, 16);

g.DrawImage(tcMain.ImageList.Images[_tabPage.ImageIndex], tabImage);
```

You could also use `ImageKey` instead of `ImageIndex`.

```
g.DrawImage(tcMain.ImageList.Images[_tabPage.ImageKey], tabImage);
```

If you add the `ImageList` and the `ImageIndex` programmatically take a look:

```
ImageList imageList = new ImageList();
imageList.Images.Add("key1", Image.FromFile("pathtofile"));
imageList.Images.Add("key2", Image.FromFile("pathtofile"));

tcMain.ImageList = imageList;
tcMain.TabPages[0].ImageIndex = 1;
tcMain.TabPages[1].ImageIndex = 0;
```

Comment: This is brilliant, it worked 90% except that the tab control now is not stable. I mean as if it is a video showing and hiding alone. Also the text has disappeared

Comment: What do you mean with "a video showing and hiding alone"?

Comment: Actually, I have got a picture only for the first tab and it is always changing from from each picture in the imagelist!

Comment: Yes Mr. Roman I did. I think this code always refer to the first tab page. The picture in the first tab page is placed properly because when I increase the top location of the drawing point it does not show up at all, while all the other picture they can go out of the tab control when I do the same. The code needs to refer to each tab page

Comment: Why no use the GetTabRect as the original code does??

Comment: @TaW Oh, thanks for the hint, I don't know why I didn't notice that.

Comment: @HilalAl-Rajhi Please notice the edit I made in the answer on line `g.DrawImage()`. Just use `_tabBounds` instead of location.

Comment: Ok, that answer fills the picture in the whole button, its good at least location issue is solved but it is not displayed with its original size and it is still like an old video

Comment: Change the `Size` property of your `Rectangle`.

Comment: I did the changes. All pictures in the proper button location even if the size is big. But It is shaking as if the pictures are redrawn every single moment

Comment: This is because you set `ImageIndex` in your `DrawItem` event. The event triggers multiple time and always reset the image. Move `tcMain.ImageList = imgList;
tcMain.TabPages[0].ImageIndex = 1;
tcMain.TabPages[1].ImageIndex = 0;
tcMain.TabPages[2].ImageIndex = 3;
tcMain.TabPages[3].ImageIndex = 2;` out of your `DrawItem` event and put it in your `Form_Load` event.

Comment: one more thing to mention, how to locate the text after each picture at a specific point from left?

Comment: Use `tcMain.SelectedPage.Text`

Comment: I tried: tcMain.SelectedTab.Text.PadLeft(50); but it has not changed

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missunderstood you. This should help you: `_tabBounds.Location += new Size(50, 0);`

Comment: Any idea on how to make spaces between tabs?

Comment: You should create a new question for new problems/questions. Because this question/answer is about something else, so other programmers who have the same questions/problems as you will not find the solution.

Comment: Yes, would you please follow the link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332416/c-sharp-tab-control-maintain-spaces-between-tabs